# How to cross out text with onpress clickHandler

Tags: react-native, onpress

I am trying to have a button cross out text with 'line-through'. I am not sure how to connect this to the button.

'''

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('shaun')

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setName('shaun (CROSSED OUT)');
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>My name is {name}</Text>
      <Text></Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title='update state' onPress={clickHandler} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a state variable to keep track of it.

quick example -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('shaun')
  const [crossedOut, setCrossedOut] = useState(false) // extra state variable

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setName('shaun (CROSSED OUT)');
    setCrossedOut(true) // set it to true on click
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* apply style only if crossedOut is true */}
      <Text style={crossedOut && {textDecorationLine: 'line-through'}}>My name is {name}</Text> 
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title='update state' onPress={clickHandler} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```